# How to make a post accessible from multiple post type slugs?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

**I have two custom post types**

1. colors
2. shapes

**I have a post called "red" under the custom post type "colors"**. The default URL for this post would be

> example.com/colors/red

Now **I want to make it accessible from the following URL** as well

> example.com/shapes/red

The closest I came with is to add a filter to change_404_template (as I receive a 404 for above url) and forcefully inject the single.php file with some hacky code.

Is there a way more standard method to do this ?

Comment: When using apache you could do a rewrite rule from shapes to colors.

Comment: Thanks. But there's no way to know if the correct post type is shapes or colors from the htaccess itself.